# How do JavaScript promises execute their code?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

Here's some code I stole from https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies and slightly modified.

```js
var momIsHappy = false;

var getAPhone = function (whatToDoIfPhoneIsPurchased,
                          whatToDoIfPhoneIsNotPurchased) {
  fulfillPromiseToPurchasePhone = whatToDoIfPhoneIsPurchased;
  breakPromiseToPurchasePhone = whatToDoIfPhoneIsNotPurchased;

  if (momIsHappy) {
      var phone = {
          brand: 'Samsung',
          color: 'black'
      };
      fulfillPromiseToPurchasePhone(phone); // fulfilled
  } else {
      var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
      breakPromiseToPurchasePhone(reason); // reject
  }
}

var aPhoneIMightGet = new Promise(getAPhone);

var playWithNewPhone = function () {
    findOutIfIGetPhone = aPhoneIMightGet;

    findOutIfIGetPhone
    .then(function (aPhone) {
        // yay, you got a new phone
        console.log(aPhone);
     // output: { brand: 'Samsung', color: 'black' }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // oops, mom don't buy it
        console.log(error.message);
     // output: 'mom is not happy'
    });
};
```

What I don't understand is: when is `getAPhone` called? I didn't call it. Who called it? When? How?

Comment: The Promise constructor accepts a function as a parameter, and that function is run immediately when the Promise is created.

Comment: So then why doesn't the code block inside the Promise's constructor? Isn't it a function on the call stack like everything else?

Comment: You did call it at `findOutIfIGetPhone.then(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Let's back up a bit and describe what the Promise constructor does.  The Promise constructor is passed a callback that is called synchronously.  The idea behind this callback (which is often called the "Promise executor callback") is that it will initiate some asynchronous operation and then immediately return.  Some time later when that asynchronous operation is done, it will then resolve or reject that promise.

Here's a simple example that we can go through step by step (you can run this example in the snippet below to see the logging sequence):

```js
console.log("0");
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("2");
        resolve("done");
    }, 1000);
}).then(function(val) {
    console.log("3");
});
console.log("4");
```

You will get this output:

```
0     // start of the code
1     // Promise executor callback called and setTimeout() initiated
4     // Promise created and now initialized
2     // setTimeout fires
3     // Promise gets resolved and .then() handler called
```

And, here are the sequence of events that happen:

1. `console.log("0");` runs
2. You call `new Promise()` and pass it a callback function
3. The Promise constructor runs, creates a promise object and synchronously calls the callback function
4. The purpose of the callback function is to initiate some non-blocking, asynchronous operation (in this case a simple `setTimeout()`), but it could be a much more complex operation such as doing some file operation, searching a database, etc...
5. The callback function is passed two arguments, each of which is a function.  The callback should call one of those two functions when the asynchronous operation that was initiated in the callback completes.  If this is a typical asynchronous operation, the callback will start the asynchronous operation and then return.  Then sometime later a different callback associated with the asynchronous operation will get called and depending upon whether the operation was successful or returned an error, that callback will then call one of the two functions that were passed to the callback (which I named `resolve` and `reject` in my example.  Your example picks much longer names.
6. In my code example, the Promise callback (called the Promise executor), immediately logs to the console and then calls `setTimeout()`.  Because `setTimeout()` is non-blocking and asynchronous, it starts the timer and immediately returns.  At this point, the Promise executor callback is done and returns.
7. The timer is now running, the promise executor callback has run and has returned.  The promise constructor is done and it returns the new Promise object.
8. Then, the `.then()` method on the promise is called.  That registers a fulfill callback for the promise and then immediately returns.  Technically, it returns a second promise that is chained to the first one that was created with the Promise constructor.  This `.then()` callback that was registered is stored away, but not yet called.
9. Now the last line of code in this example executes and it logs `4` to the console.
10. This code is done (for now).  Any other code that follows this would execute now or if there is no other code, then the Javascript interpreter goes back to the event loop and waits for the next event to occur.
11. Sometime later, the timer fires.  It inserts an event in the Javascript event queue and when the interpreter is done doing anything else it was doing and fetches the next event from the event queue, it will call the callback that was passed to `setTimeout()`.
12. When that `setTimeout()` callback executes, it will log `2` and then call `resolve("done")`.  Calling `resolve()` resolves the first promise and tells it to then trigger any `.then()` handlers and call them.
13. At this point, the callback passed to `.then()` is called and it logs `3` and everything is done.

Now to answer some of the specific questions about your code example:

> What I don't understand is: when is getAPhone called? I didn't call it. Who called it? When? How?

You passed `getAPhone` to the Promise constructor.  The Promise constructor calls it as part of running the constructor to create the new Promise object.

Here's a simple example of how that happens:

```
function doIt(someCallback) {
    someCallback("hi");
}

function myCallback(greeting) {
   console.log(greeting);
}

doIt(myCallback);    // logs "greeting"
```

When you call doIt, you pass it a function reference (essentially a pointer to a function).  This allows the function you're calling to call the function with whatever arguments it wants to when it wants to call it.  In this case, `doIt()` expects you to pass it one function reference and it will immediately call that function and pass it `"hi"`.

> So why doesn't the promise constructor just block my code when it runs my function? If all the constructor is doing is immediately calling a function for me, why is it different from just calling the function directly?

The promise constructor is run synchronously (when you call `new Promise()`).  The promise executor callback function is run synchronously by the Promise constructor.  But, what it typically does is just initiate an asynchronous and non-blocking operation and then immediately returns.  The asynchronous operation then runs in the background and will trigger it's own callback sometime in the future when it completes.

> So then why doesn't the code block inside the Promise's constructor? Isn't it a function on the call stack like everything else?

The Promise constructor is blocking.  It doesn't return until it finishes.  It is a function on the call stack like everything else.

What may be confusing you here is that your `getAPhone()` example does not contain any asynchronous code.  It's entirely synchronous.  There is NO reason to use promises with that code at all.

Here's a little less obtuse version of that function:

```
var momIsHappy = false;

var getAPhone = function (resolve, reject) {
  if (momIsHappy) {
      var phone = {
          brand: 'Samsung',
          color: 'black'
      };
      resolve(phone); // fulfilled
  } else {
      var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
      reject(reason); // reject
  }
}
```

All this does is examine `momIsHappy` and then immediately resolve or reject the promise.  There is no asynchronous operation here.  ***There is no reason to use promises with your example at all.***  Promises are tools for managing and coordinating asynchronous operations.  You should not use them if you don't have any asynchronous operations because they add complexity to synchronous code when plain and simpler function calls can be used instead.  With asynchronous operations, it can be difficult to coordinate and manage asynchronous operations and error handling, particularly when there are multiple asynchronous operations that need to be sequenced or coordinated and all errors handled.  That's what promises are designed for.

**So, in your specific case, you could have just made `getAPhone()` into a regular function, just called it directly and not used promises at all.**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard to test with a simple example:

```js
function someFun() {
    console.log("testing")
}
let p = new Promise(someFun)
```

So even though we didn't do anything with the promise the function still called by the promise constructor when you make the promise and runs synchronously. In a more realistic scenario you would pass it a function with a resolve callback that is executed when the async operation is finished, but the function passed into `new Promise()` still fires immediately:

```js
function someFun(resolve) {
    console.log("someFun called")
    setTimeout(() => resolve("promise resolved"), 1500)
}
console.log("starting")

let p = new Promise(someFun)
.then(console.log)

console.log("just called the promise")
```

Comment: So why doesn't the promise constructor just block my code when it runs my function? If all the constructor is doing is immediately calling a function for me, why is it different from just calling the function directly?

Comment: It doesn’t block because ’setTimeout‘ doesn’t block. It registers the timer with resolve as the callback and continues with the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is: when is "getAPhone" called? I didn't call
>   it. Who called it? When? How?

Answering this more directly, perhaps: when you assign the new Promise to the variable, "aPhoneIMightGet", the constructor is run as stated by Mark Meyer above.

Your "getAPhone" is an "executer function" passed into the Promise constructor. As such, it is executed immediately, and before the Promise constructor returns. This is what calls your "getAPhone" function.

A good article that might help can be found [here](https://medium.com/@ramsunvtech/promises-of-promise-part-1-53f769245a53).

Comment: So why doesn't the promise constructor just block my code when it runs my function? If all the constructor is doing is immediately calling a function for me, why is it different from just calling the function directly?

Comment: Promises are asynchronous, and non-blocking. They immediately return right after the call, though the promise may not yet be resolved. If you were to call your function directly, it would "block", as it is executed in javascript's single thread of execution. That's the idea behind promises... Rather than block when called, they allow a potentially long process-- a calculation, db query, etc.-- to not block during it's execution. Once a result is obtained, the promise returns by executing either the resolve or error function